# Standard Normal Distribution Question

Tags: statistics

If a set of measurements are normally distributed, what percentage of these differ from the mean by more than half of the standard deviation?

Attempt:
P(z > 0.5) = 1-P(z < 0.5) = 1-0.6915 = 0.3085

The correct answer is 0.0617; I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The correct answer is $0.617$ And a now deleted comment was right: you need to calculate $P(|Z|>1/2)$ rather than $P(Z>1/2).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you are supposed  to be calculating $P[|z| > 0.5]$, since you want the observation to be more than half a standard deviation away from the mean (of the standard normal) in the positive *and negative* directions, not merely in one of these directions. This would be evaluated as $ 1 - \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx = 0.617$, which is similar to your answer, except you seem to have an extra decimal point, but that would be a printing mistake, most likely.

(I did not need to calculate this value once you had done it : you may have noticed that $0.3085$ is half the correct answer, due to the symmetry of the standard normal).

Answer (score 0):

What you have to find are the regions more than "half *away*", in two directions, which includes both the regions $-\infty < x < -0.5$ and $0.5 < x < \infty$.

We can use an [online calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html) to get that the region *in between* $-0.5$ and $0.5$ is equal to around $0.3829$. Since the whole distribution sums to $1$, we can subtract $0.3829$ from $1$ to get $0.6171$.

Comment: Some online calculators don't support calculating values *outside* two numbers, so I used a different way to get my answer.